# how to get specific page content

Tags: pages, get-posts

bellow is my code working nice but problem is don't coming with html tag.. like    etc... no idea why...

```
  <?php $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=2"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
    <?php 
    echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,450);

     ?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
             More About Us
              </a>
```

bellow is another code which is html tag and everything ok.. but i can't figure out how to permalink do there.. the permalink i put there i not work.

```
<?php
$my_id = 2;
$page_id = get_post($my_id);
$content = $page_id->post_content;
echo substr($content, 0, 450);

?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" >More About Us</a>
```

also what is best way to get specific page content like bellow way

```
<h2>title</h2>
<div>featured image </div>
<div>content</div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than call `WP_Query()` you can use `get_post()` and "set up" the `global $post`. This is probably a little more efficient than @tf's answer, though the ideas are broadly the same.

*Please note, in both cases you should reset the post data afterwards.*

```
/**
 * Display the post content. Optionally allows post ID to be passed
 * @uses the_content()
 *
 * @param int $id Optional. Post ID.
 * @param string $more_link_text Optional. Content for when there is more text.
 * @param bool $stripteaser Optional. Strip teaser content before the more text. Default is false.
 */
function sh_the_content_by_id( $post_id=0, $more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = false ){
    global $post;
    $post = &get_post($post_id);
    setup_postdata( $post, $more_link_text, $stripteaser );
    the_content();
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Source: http://stephenharris.info/get-post-content-by-id/

Comment: Well, the _logic_ is not mine - I just took what's in the question, and improved that a little. ;) If it is just one post, one is interested in, you are, of course, right - in using `get_post`. However, since the loop was there in the first place, I let it be.

Comment: link broken url

Answer (score 2):

[`(get_)the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) strips HTML tags - that's why you don't have HTML tags. ;)

Just use `the_content()` instead of `the_excerpt()` if you want to show the full content.

```
$recent = new WP_Query("page_id=2");
while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="bookmark">Permalink</a>';
    the_content();
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

As for the *best way* of outputting post data, you should have a look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Post_tags).